# how to get the coldfusion instance server name

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

this is my code .

```
<cfhttp  method="head" url="http://www.sisystems.com" result="myResult">
<cfoutput>
  #myResult.Statuscode#

</cfoutput>
```

This code gives the status code for this url . i need to know in which coldfusion server  it  hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the coldfusion server instance name using coldfusion adminapi as below

```
runtime = createObject("component", "CFIDE.adminapi.runtime");
instanceName = runtime.getInstanceName();
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank u soo much .. one more doubt . how to get the name of a particular server which processes my http or https request behind the loadbalancer in a server farm? please help me

Comment: Take a look at the CGI scope. It may be present in one of the CGI variables. Do you need ColdFusion to use the server name, or do you want to see which server handled the request when you're using/debugging the site? If it's the latter, you can tell the HTTP server to add an extra header. In Apache you'd add 'Header set x-http-server http-server-1a' to httpd.conf and change the value it's using for each different apache instance. the same approach will work in IIS, but the config will be different

Comment: As indicated by Barnyr, the server name is here: cgi.server_name         
so if you want to retain this name (so you can differentiate between your Dev Box server name and the Production instance server name)                                           (so you can do things like correcting the time of day for display in your app - because your local time is different than the Production Server's time...),                                                                                                  
             just do: <cfset session.server_name = cgi.server_name>

Answer (score 2):

*For your question in the comments of Sunny's answer* - You can use the following Java methods to gather information about the particular server that ColdFusion is running on:

```
<cfset cfHostName = createObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress").localhost.getHostName() />
<cfset cfCanonName = createObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress").localhost.getCanonicalHostName() />
<cfset cfHostAddress = createObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress").localhost.getHostAddress() />
```

And prior to ColdFusion 10, when ColdFusion is running on JRun you can also use the following:

```
<cfset cfInstance = createObject("java", "jrunx.kernel.JRun").getServerName() />
```